# WPF Button does not show ToolTip when TapAndHold consecutively

Tags: c#, wpf, button, tooltip

I'm implementing a .NET 4.5 WPF application on a touchscreen desktop. When testing my application, I realised that the tooltips for my buttons will not appear when I tap and hold the same button twice consecutively.

1) I tap and hold on Button A once, the tooltip for Button A appears as expected. 
2) I tap and hold on Button A again (after the initial tooltip has disappeared), the tooltip will not appear again. 
3) I tap and hold on Button B, tooltip for Button B appears. 
4) I tap and hold on Button A now, tooltip for Button A now able to appear.

I am not sure whether this is the default behavior or it's something I did somewhere in my code that caused this to happen. Is there anything I can do to ensure the tooltip appears everytime?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <MvvmLight:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MessageInfoVm.ShowInfoMessageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ToolTipOk}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Button ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipOk}"  Command="{Binding OkCommand}" />
        </ContentControl>
```

Try ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
or additional event for MouseLeftButtonDown